# Safari Bug with elements innerText

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Okay I asked this question a little while ago but I have some pictures to show of this bug I'm getting with safari.

In the console area safari shows this text

```
<div id="rot3posDisp" class="rotDisp">C</div>
```

But on the actual page it still has the `innerText` as 'B'.
This means the `innerText` isn't being refreshed by the javascript function I have enplace.

Has anyone else had this bug with safari and if so, do you have a work around.

Comment: Do some searching on innerHTML and Safari. there seems to be some inherent issues with it, on that browser.

Comment: Have you updated your js file recently? If so, an older version might be cached

Comment: No, it is up to date. This bug only seems to show up with safari, I'm looking into the innerHTML inherit issues right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can stick to IE9+, `.textContent` is preferred. `.innerText` doesn't work in Firefox at all.

```
document.getElementById('rot3posDisp').textContent = 'C';
```